# Finding MD5 String From Certain Text

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, find

in my Vb Winform Program I have a text Box Which Receives html source code of a website.
there is a MD5 hash with 32 Characters which I want it. every time that the site gives new MD5 hash, everything in the Source code is like before, just with different MD5 hash code. there is a part in source code which contains that MD5 Hash. It always appears in Source code after "crash-row crash-" like below:

crash-row crash-203c7e7a01da28d4e437a88b192b69a3

so I should write a code for finding "crash-row crash-" from my source code (which is in my text box) and then copys 32 characters after that for me.
can anyone help me? I am So confused.

Comment: Find the text, substring what you need, then do with it whatever you need to do.

Comment: Use [String.IndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_) to figure out where `crash-row crash-` is, then use `String.SubString()` to get the characters you want as already suggested.  You'll need to add the length of the string you're searching for to get the proper starting point.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Man I do not know how to thank you. You saved my life. It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `String.SubString` for this:

```
Dim str As String = TextBox1.Text
'We start from 16 because that is where the required string starts.
Dim result As String = str.Substring(16, 32)
MessageBox.Show(result)
```